# How can I get indexes after getting NER results?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

```
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english")
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
from transformers import LukeTokenizer
from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast



label_list = [
    "O",       # Outside of a named entity
    "B-MISC",  # Beginning of a miscellaneous entity right after another miscellaneous entity
    "I-MISC",  # Miscellaneous entity
    "B-PER",   # Beginning of a person's name right after another person's name
    "I-PER",   # Person's name
    "B-ORG",   # Beginning of an organisation right after another organisation
    "I-ORG",   # Organisation
    "B-LOC",   # Beginning of a location right after another location
    "I-LOC"    # Location
]

sequence = "Hugging Face Inc. is a company based in New York City. Its headquarters are in DUMBO, therefore very" \
           "close to the Manhattan Bridge."

# Bit of a hack to get the tokens with the special tokens
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(tokenizer.decode(tokenizer.encode(sequence)))
inputs = tokenizer.encode(sequence, return_tensors="pt")

outputs = model(inputs)[0]
predictions = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=2)

print([(token, label_list[prediction]) for token, prediction in zip(tokens, predictions[0].tolist())])

output:    [('[CLS]', 'O'), ('Hu', 'I-ORG'), ('##gging', 'I-ORG'), ('Face', 'I-ORG'), ('Inc', 'I-ORG'), 
    ('.', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('a', 'O'), ('company', 'O'), ('based', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('New', 'I-
    LOC'), ('York', 'I-LOC'), ('City', 'I-LOC'), ('.', 'O'), ('Its', 'O'), ('headquarters', 'O'), 
    ('are', 'O'), ('in', 'O'), ('D', 'I-LOC'), ('##UM', 'I-LOC'), ('##BO', 'I-LOC'), (',', 'O'), 
    ('therefore', 'O'), ('very', 'O'), ('##c', 'O'), ('##lose', 'O'), ('to', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), 
    ('Manhattan', 'I-LOC'), ('Bridge', 'I-LOC'), ('.', 'O'), ('[SEP]', 'O')]
```

I took an example from the Hugging Face Transformers documentation in order to understand how the library works. But I ran into a problem that I can't solve for a very long time. After getting the output that is in "print", I want to get the indices of the recognized entities for the "sequence" variable. How can I do this? Didn't find any method in the documentation, am I missing something?

For example:

> ('Hu', 'I-ORG'), ('##gging', 'I-ORG'), ('Face', 'I-ORG'), ('Inc',
> 'I-ORG') ---> (start: 0, end: 16)

**Additional question:** Should I get rid off ## (for example: ('##gging', 'I-ORG')) in my results? Or this is okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you are trying to achieve is already available as [tokenclassificationpipeline](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#tokenclassificationpipeline):

```py
from transformers import pipeline

ner =  pipeline('token-classification', model='dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english', tokenizer='dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english')

sentence = "Hugging Face Inc. is a company based in New York City. Its headquarters are in DUMBO, therefore very" \
           "close to the Manhattan Bridge."

ner(sentence)
```

Output:

```
[{'end': 2,
  'entity': 'I-ORG',
  'index': 1,
  'score': 0.9995108,
  'start': 0,
  'word': 'Hu'},
 {'end': 7,
  'entity': 'I-ORG',
  'index': 2,
  'score': 0.98959744,
  'start': 2,
  'word': '##gging'},
 {'end': 12,
  'entity': 'I-ORG',
  'index': 3,
  'score': 0.9979704,
  'start': 8,
  'word': 'Face'},
 {'end': 16,
  'entity': 'I-ORG',
  'index': 4,
  'score': 0.9993759,
  'start': 13,
  'word': 'Inc'},
 {'end': 43,
  'entity': 'I-LOC',
  'index': 11,
  'score': 0.9993406,
  'start': 40,
  'word': 'New'},
 {'end': 48,
  'entity': 'I-LOC',
  'index': 12,
  'score': 0.99919283,
  'start': 44,
  'word': 'York'},
 {'end': 53,
  'entity': 'I-LOC',
  'index': 13,
  'score': 0.99934113,
  'start': 49,
  'word': 'City'},
 {'end': 80,
  'entity': 'I-LOC',
  'index': 19,
  'score': 0.9863364,
  'start': 79,
  'word': 'D'},
 {'end': 82,
  'entity': 'I-LOC',
  'index': 20,
  'score': 0.939624,
  'start': 80,
  'word': '##UM'},
 {'end': 84,
  'entity': 'I-LOC',
  'index': 21,
  'score': 0.9121385,
  'start': 82,
  'word': '##BO'},
 {'end': 122,
  'entity': 'I-LOC',
  'index': 29,
  'score': 0.983919,
  'start': 113,
  'word': 'Manhattan'},
 {'end': 129,
  'entity': 'I-LOC',
  'index': 30,
  'score': 0.99242425,
  'start': 123,
  'word': 'Bridge'}]
```

You can also group the tokens by defining a aggregation strategy:

```py
ner(sentence, aggregation_strategy='simple')
```

Output:

```
[{'end': 16,
  'entity_group': 'ORG',
  'score': 0.9966136,
  'start': 0,
  'word': 'Hugging Face Inc'},
 {'end': 53,
  'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.9992916,
  'start': 40,
  'word': 'New York City'},
 {'end': 84,
  'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.946033,
  'start': 79,
  'word': 'DUMBO'},
 {'end': 129,
  'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.98817164,
  'start': 113,
  'word': 'Manhattan Bridge'}]
```